# The lift and the right hand sides for Piecewise limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Considering this limit :

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} =
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & \text{x≠1} \\[2ex]
\pi , & \text{x=1}
\end{cases}$.

**from the lift :**

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1-} (x+1) = 2 $

**from the right:**

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1+} (\pi) = \pi  $

I'm assuming that this limit is not exist since the left hand side limit does not equal the right hand side limit (From my current knowledge).

The Book that i use telling me not what i expected !:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} =
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & \text{x≠1} \\[2ex]
\pi , & \text{x=1}
\end{cases}$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} (x+1) = 2 $

I think i miss some things about Piecewise limits. anyone explain to me why this limit end up with 2 ?

Comment: You are not calculating the limit from the right correctly. This limit should also be $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that, according to the definition, when we take the limit $x\to 1$ we are assuming $x\neq 1$, that is

$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \text{such that}\quad \color{green}{\forall x\neq1}\quad|x-1|<\delta \implies|f(x)-2|<\varepsilon$$

therefore since $x\neq 1$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} (x+1) = 2$$

In other words, the value for the limit at a point is not affected by the value of the function at that point. The function could be also not defined at that point (e.g. $\sin x/x$ as $x \to 0$).

Your evaluation would be correct for the following function

$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & \text{$x<1$} \\[2ex]
\pi  & \text{$x\ge1$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: OK, got the idea

Comment: @AmmarBamhdi Well done! Keep always that in mind. Bye